# How to get distinct closest date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I don't know how to format?!, but I believe it's easy to understand.
I have the following table, lets call it "sales"

```
|Item|        |Price|        |PriceDate|  
ItemA          801.36         09/23/2011  
ItemA          800.64         09/23/2011  
ItemA          803.55         09/22/2011  
ItemB          4701.36         09/22/2011  
ItemB          1101.36         09/22/2011  
ItemB          4801.36         09/20/2011  
ItemB          401.36         09/22/2011    
ItemC          9601.36         09/21/2011  
ItemC          201.36         09/19/2011  
ItemC          301.36         09/17/2011
```

I'm given a date and I need to retrieve the records with the closest date, and only those, for example, if 09/24/2011 is the input, the output should be only the records from the 23rd for item A, 22nd for itemB, and 21st for itemC.

Using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What steps have you taken to try and solve this problem on your own?

Comment: How do you define closest? Is it before the input date or after, or both?

Comment: I tried to use the rank function but failed miserably, Im really a newbie in SQL Server. I define "closest" as BEFORE the input date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to go about it is to calculate the difference between the row's data and the given date by using [`datediff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx), assign a [`rank`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) to each row accordingly and filter by it.

Here I'm using `?` as a placeholder for the required date, just switch it with the correct syntax of the language you're using:

```
SELECT item, price, pricedate
FROM   (SELECT item, price, pricedate,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY item
                            ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(day, pricedate, ?))) AS rk
        FROM   salse) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: Note that the rank windowed function (which I also used) will consider 1 day before and 1 day after to be of equal rank, and will return them both.

Comment: @RossPresser by the OP's description, this seems like the correct behavior - they are both one dat away from the given date. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything at all. My "note" did not mean to imply to the OP "this may not be what you want", just "don't be surprised by this".

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @theTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(10), price DECIMAL(10,2), priceDate DATE)
INSERT @theTable ( Item, price, priceDate )
VALUES  
('ItemA',801.36,'2011-09-23'),
('ItemA',800.64,'2011-09-23'),
('ItemA',803.55,'2011-09-22'),
('ItemB',4701.36,'2011-09-22'),
('ItemB',1101.36,'2011-09-22'),
('ItemB',4801.36,'2011-09-20'),
('ItemB',401.36,'2011-09-22'),
('ItemC',9601.36,'2011-09-21'),
('ItemC',201.36,'2011-09-19'),
('ItemC',301.36,'2011-09-17')

DECLARE @inputDate DATE
SET @inputDate = '2011-09-24'

SELECT X.Item, X.price, X.priceDate FROM (
SELECT TT.Item, TT.price, TT.priceDate, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Item] 
                          ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, @inputDate, TT.priceDate))) AS RN
FROM @theTable TT 
) AS X
WHERE RN = 1
```

---

> ```
> (10 row(s) affected)
> Item       price                                   priceDate
> ---------- --------------------------------------- ----------
> ItemA      801.36                                  2011-09-23
> ItemA      800.64                                  2011-09-23
> ItemB      4701.36                                 2011-09-22
> ItemB      1101.36                                 2011-09-22
> ItemB      401.36                                  2011-09-22
> ItemC      9601.36                                 2011-09-21
> ```

Answer (score -1):

i have the same problem but i found that i can solve it on front end by easier way

```
/*back end*/
/*(DistinctItem)   select distinct Item from sales*/
/*(saleRecords)    select * from sales order by PriceDate desc*/

/*front end*/
for(var j = 0; j < DistinctItem.length;j++){
  for(var i = 0; i < saleRecords.length;i++){
    if(DistinctItem[j].Item==saleRecords[i].Item){
      if(anyDate>saleRecords[i].PriceDate){
        use saleRecords[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cheuk, please include code as *text*, not as an image